# Cannot remove passphrase from private key with openssl

Tags: heroku, openssl, passphrase

All the web pages our there suggest removing the passphrase from a private key file by running a simple openssl command.  But when I run the command it does not ask for my current passphrase or remove it from the newly created one.

Here is what I run:

```
MacBookPro:simplegym harris$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
MacBookPro:simplegym harris$ openssl rsa -in KeyWithPassphrase.key -out KeyWithoutPassphrase.key 
writing RSA key
MacBookPro:simplegym harris$
```

Unfortunately the KeyWithoutPassphrase.key that is generated DOES have a passphrase?

This is BIG issue for me because Heroku will not accept a private key with a passphrase in order to configure an SSL certificate.

Ideas???

Thanks for any help,

--harris

Comment: That command is exactly how you should do it. Why do you believe it's not removing the passphrase?

Comment: Try changing output file extension to .pem, instead of .key